# Action not working in Controller even tho I just duplicated existing one

Tags: cakephp

I have to modify a platform made in CakePHP 2.x, first time working with MVC and I'm a bit confused.
I actually want to delete some data from database, long way till there..
For now I just want to know how can I make another route work and show some content there.

I have a SubmissionsController which has a few functions like index or import2.
When I go to /submissions/index2 it works, I tried to duplicate the function import2 in SubmissionsController, same with the view in View/Submissions/delete.ctp

routes.php

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
Router::connect('/logout', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'));
Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

SubmissionController.php

```
function index2() {
    $this->Paginator->settings = array('limit' => 250); 
    $this->set('submits', $this->Paginator->paginate('Submit'));
}
function delete() {
    $this->Paginator->settings = array('limit' => 250); 
    $this->set('submits', $this->Paginator->paginate('Submit'));
}
```

https://pastebin.com/6Sw6ykuf - this is the whole SubmissionController.php
https://pastebin.com/3iujwrBH  - delete.ctp or index2.ctp

/submissions/index2 shows me the View/Submissions/index2.ctp
If I access the /submissions/delete I should see same page right?
But I get redirected to the homepage instead. I tried to debug() but don't know how to use it exactly.

Comment: read https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::render

Comment: function delete() {
  $this->render('Submissions.delete');
 }
And still get redirected to home, no error or something.

Comment: Is there any authorization in the app that might not be allowing access to the new function?

Comment: @GregSchmidt There is authorization, but i'm logged in. Is this what you mean?

Comment: $this->Auth->allow( 'delete'); I had to do this in AppController.php. Why It has to be done for delete but not for index2 for example?

Comment: Something equivalent to this must be happening somewhere else. Maybe a database-driven process?

Comment: @GregSchmidt Can you help me understand this? I've searched in the whole code for index2 and nothing like that came up.

Comment: Did you search for other occurrences of `$this->Auth->allow`? Search a database dump for `index2`? There are so many possible ways that the code could be structured that it's simply not possible to tell you everywhere to look.